# Adding User Controls To Web Page in VB.Net Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have followed the setup instructions at this link [Adding Controls to a webpage](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/creating-a-basic-web-forms-page)

However, for the 2 weeks that I have been studying vb.net, I have yet to be able to add a drag and drop form or control element on the page as all options are grayed out...even while in design view.  Is there a setting I am overlooking?  It doesn't make any sense that there would be tutorials on how to do the exact thing I am trying to do, but for some reason, it does not allow me to do it on my setup.  Please help!?

Comment: What version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: This is happening only when creating a web application.  I can create a form application and add user controls and form elements, no problems; but not to a web application.  If I can't resolve this, can you point me in the right direction of how to create an windows form app and combine it with a web app?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...rookie mistake.  I figured it out. I was still running and debugging the application.  Must stop the application from running and then all form controls become "addable".

Hope this saves someone time.